# Javascript async how to await for a varying number of uploadTasks to all be completed?

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await, firebase-storage

I have `saveBlogPost()` function that needs to perform the following actions:

- Call the `uploadImages()` function to update the images of the blogPost to Firebase storage. Number of images is not fixed.
- **Wait for the upload for all images to complete** with success or error. If success the URL for each images will be available in the blogPost object.
- Act based on the result of the upload

  - If success: save post to Firestore
  - If fail: display error message to the user

**My question is how to wait for a varying number of uploads?**

Here is my code so far:

---

**savePost() function:**

```
function savePost() {
  uploadImages();
}
```

**uploadImages() function:**

**Note:** `images` is an array of the image files to be uploaded.

```
function uploadImages() {
  images.forEach((image) => {
    const uploadTask = storageRef.put(file,metadata);
    uploadTask.on('state_changed',
      function progress() {
        //UPLOAD PROGRESS BAR
      },
      function error(err) {
        //SET ERROR
      },
      function complete() {
        //UPDATE IMAGE URL IN BLOGPOST OBJECT
        //SET COMPLETE
      }
  });
}
```

**QUESTION:**

My intent is to make `savePost()` function `async` and `await` for the `uploadImages()` function. But how can I **resolve/reject** the `uploadImages()` function only after ALL the images have **resolved/rejected** ?

Something like:

```
async function savePost() {
    const result = await uploadImages();
    // ACT BASED ON RESULT
  }
```

But I don't know what to do with the `uploadImages()` function in order to **resolve/reject** only after all the images are done.

How can I do this?

Comment: Check out `Promise.all()` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: I've checked that, but they only have examples of fixed number of promises. In my case the number of promises vary with the number of images to be uploaded. How can I handle that?

Comment: Why don't you create an array to hold array of promises?  then loop through the array using promise.all?

Comment: Something like this: `Promise.all(images.map(uploadImage))` (see Aleksandr's answer)

Comment: I'll try that! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function uploadImages() {
    const promises = images.map(async image =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const uploadTask = storageRef.put(file, metadata);
            uploadTask.on('state_changed',
                function progress() {
                    //UPLOAD PROGRESS BAR
                },
                function error(err) {
                    //SET ERROR
                    reject(err);
                },
                function complete() {
                    //UPDATE IMAGE URL IN BLOGPOST OBJECT
                    //SET COMPLETE
                    resolve();
                }
            );
        })
    );

    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: Just note that `storageRef.put(file,metadata)` returns an `uploadTask` (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask.html) on which you can also call `then()`. So actually no need to do `new Promise((resolve, reject) ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

A `forEach` loop will not work for `async / await` as you would like it to work.

Try using a simple `for` loop:

```
for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
    let response = await savePost();
}
```